# Allow to ask questions anonymously in Teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

In Stack Overflow for Teams, can the OP choose to be anonymous?

We currently use [Starmind](https://www.starmind.com/) and I want to propose [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams). A big selling point for Starmind is that people can ask questions anonymously without risking appearing stupid in front of their peers. Answers are eponymous.

Can [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) do this as well? I was thinking of an *Ask Anonymously* checkbox.

---

Clarifications:

- **The question does not apply to Stack Overflow proper:** It is specifically for Teams.
- **Removing a barrier to entry:** My company is quite big with offices in many countries. Many colleagues are experts in their subject area and new(er) hires don't want their first impression to be - what they feel is - a silly question. Comments on the workplace itself are off-topic, so please refrain.

Comment: I dislike the idea. But as long as they do not bring it over to the real SO and it's an optional feature in teams... meh.

Comment: I would support this for SOfT. The real SO can already be anonymous - just sign up for a new account. It's important that people can submit questions, and it is a key concern for my company adopting it. Whilst I personally feel comfortable with asking any question, some people do worry that they would looks silly asking a question